# How to run AWS locally sam start API or sam debugger with HTTPS localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vscode-debugger, sam

I'm trying to use the AWS SAM Debugger but I need that the URL being HTTPS://my.localhost:3000 rather than HTTP://localhost:3000

I don't know how to modify the SAM's docker file or maybe another easier way.

Thanks...